# Amazon Web Service: Use non csv data and retrieve trained model

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, nifti

I am considering using the AWS with the machine learning AMI for training some deep networks that are to slow for my hardware setup.

However I see at the moment two possible major issues that might make this option less interesting or even impossible.

The training data is not in csv format, but images in nifti format. In the AWS description, it is stated that the data has to be in .csv.

Additionally, the FAQ states that trained models cannot be extracted. Which means that all sub-sequential inference and testing has to be made depending on instances in the AWS?

Are both of these issues real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I assume you can use only csv format for training data:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/step-1-download-edit-and-upload-data.html
[AWS Machine Learning Datasources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/amazon-machine-learning-key-concepts.html)
and finally [Data from other products can usually be exported into CSV files in Amazon S3, making it accessible to Amazon Machine Learning](https://aws.amazon.com/aml/faqs/)

It seems that csv is the only format so far, I found it a bit frustrating myself...

And yes, as Machine Learning FAQ indicate:

> Q: Can I export my models out of Amazon Machine Learning?
>
> A: No.

So, so far, no way to save your model...
You can probably create a C5.large (compute optimized) instance and install all the Python libraries needed for your machine learning projects. Then use scikit-learn feature to save your model.
If C5.large is not going to be enough you can easily scale it up, just use EBS storage for this instance.

I hope this verification helps

Comment: I understand I can use csv, my question is as to the negative: "can I use other than csv?". The reference to the FAQ is what I meant in the question. Does this mean that one is forever dependent on the AWS for further usage of the model?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misunderstood it! Let me correct the answer

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate in the second point? Is there a reason to believe one can save a trained model and just copy it back to the local computer? Wouldn't this then be saying "yes, one can export a model out of AWS"

Comment: Not exactly from AWS Machine Learning service. You can just start a powerful enough EC2 instance on AWS cloud and install necessary software on it. This software could be machine learning libraries, like scikit-learn. Scikit-learn allows you to save a trained model, see here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: yeah thats it. I was confusing a general EC2 instance with the machine learning service, which is not what I want nor need. I thought the latest was just a EC2 instance with prepared environment for own ML projects, but its a whole toolkit service, so it makes sense that it has restricted capabilities.